# Difference between mean values of two samples

Tags: hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval, chi-squared-test, standard-deviation, mean

I have two groups with mean values and standard deviation values of the purchase power index, where `N` is the number of observations used to calculate mean and std.dev. for each group.

```
Group 1                 Group 2
Mean  Std.Dev.  N       Mean   Std.Dev.  N
2.5   0.25      100     3.2    0.8       150
```

How can I estimate the confidence percent that would indicate that the difference between mean values of two samples is not just a random result?
In general, any recommendation regarding the evaluation of the difference's confidence is highly welcome. Should I apply chi-squared test here? I appreciate any guidance. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the theoretical mean is the same for both groups, and that you do not know their theoretical standard deviation, this is the formula to calculate the confidence interval for the test of the null hypothesis of equal mean:

[image]

where $t^*$ is the critical value you want to use. This normally comes from a $t$ distribution, where the degrees of freedom given by the smaller of the two samples size. As in your case this is a large number ($100$), you can use the normal distribution to obtain this critical value (they will be very much the same). For example, for a 5% confidence interval (two sided), use $t^*=1.96$ (see [here](http://www.math.armstrong.edu/statsonline/5/5.3.2.html) for more information).

I probably do not need to calculate this interval for you, as you got all the numbers required.

More info [here](http://www.stat.yale.edu/Courses/1997-98/101/meancomp.htm).